# Angular - getting ng-bind to work on nested directives

Tags: angularjs

I've built a small pattern that recursively creates different sub-directives based on the model. I'm using `$compile` to build child directives recursively, then append them to the parent.
The directive building itself seems to work just fine, but for some reason, embedded expressions or `ng-bind` or interpolation doesn't seem to work on nested directive.

Here's a snippet:

```
app.directive("child", function ($compile) {
  function getTemplate(depth) {
    if (depth % 2 == 0) {
      return "<even depth='deeper'/>"
    } else {
      return "<odd depth='deeper'/>"
    }
  }
  return {
    scope: {
      depth: "="
    },
    link: function linker($scope, $element) {
      if ($scope.depth == 0) {
        var child = angular.element("<span ng-bind='depth'/>");
        child = $compile(child)($scope);
        $element.append(child);
      } else {
        $scope.deeper = $scope.depth - 1;
        var child = angular.element(getTemplate($scope.depth));
        child = $compile(child)($scope);
        $element.append(child);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Basically in this test the directive will recursively dive down until the `depth` reaches `0`, then spit out a `<span>` element.
The expected result should be a span element with the value of `0`. But it doesn't seem to evaluate. Using `<span>{{depth}}</span>` also results in in a literal html instead of evaluating the contents.
I'm trying to achieve a result of nested `<even><odd><even>` directives ***removing*** the surrounding `<child>` - directive.

Here's a complete jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eg1e1aLz/

The resulting DOM should look like this:

```html
<test depth="4" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <even depth="depth-1" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
    <odd depth="depth-1" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
      <even depth="depth-1" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
        <odd depth="depth-1" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><span ng-bind="depth" class="ng-binding ng-scope">0</span></odd>
      </even>
    </odd>
  </even>
</test>
```

Comment: How are you expecting the `even` and `odd` tags to invoke the `child` directive?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the fiddle...

Comment: what type of output you are expecting @Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments below and the update to the question, how about the following...

It uses the template function `getTemplate` to build the structure, and identical directives: `odd` and `even` as placeholders for building the functionality.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive("test", function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      depth: "="
    },
    link: function linker($scope, $element, $attrs) {

      // template accessible to the child directives
      $scope.getTemplate = function(depth) {
        if (depth <= 0) {
          return "<span ng-bind='depth'/>"; // also bindings like {{depth}} work
        } else if (depth % 2 === 0) {
          return "<even depth='depth-1'></even>"; // bindings like {{depth}} work
        } else {
          return "<odd depth='depth-1'></odd>";
        }
      }

      var child = angular.element($scope.getTemplate($scope.depth));
      $compile(child)($scope);
      $element.append(child);
    }
  }
});
app.directive("odd", function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      depth: "="
    },
    link: function linker($scope, $element) {
      $scope.getTemplate = $scope.$parent.getTemplate; // bring template into current scope
      var child = angular.element($scope.getTemplate($scope.depth));
      $compile(child)($scope);
      $element.append(child);
    }
  }
})
app.directive("even", function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      depth: "=",
    },
    link: function linker($scope, $element) {
      $scope.getTemplate = $scope.$parent.getTemplate; // bring template into current scope
      var child = angular.element($scope.getTemplate($scope.depth));
      $compile(child)($scope);
      $element.append(child);
    }
  }
})

var controller = app.controller("controller", function($scope) {});
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bda411fj/15/

**Result:**

```
<test depth="4" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <even depth="depth-1" class="ng-binding ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
    <odd depth="depth-1" class="ng-binding ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
      <even depth="depth-1" class="ng-binding ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
        <odd depth="depth-1" class="ng-binding ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
          <span ng-bind="depth" class="ng-binding ng-scope">0</span>
        </odd>
      </even>
    </odd>
  </even>
</test>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not the solution I was looking for. What I'm trying to do is get rid of the "child" element. I'd like to have a dynamic templating directive that would replace itself with the child.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. I'll take another look

Comment: Are you looking for `test` to call itself recursively? Did you still want to keep odd/even?

Comment: Do you mean like https://jsfiddle.net/353gtrpd/3/ (deleted the `child` directive)

Comment: Updated answer to use a single recursive directive that will spit out the span at depth 0 (https://jsfiddle.net/353gtrpd/4/). NgBind is working on the lowest level (the span). If that's not what you're looking for perhaps you could clarify your expected output

Comment: Sorry. I'm having a hard time explaining what I expect. Added the expected DOM result above. What I'd like is a directive that would **replace** itself with other directives based on model input. Not adding more children to itself, but replace itself. Similar to the approach with a templace and replace:true, but with dynamic behavior / template content. I'm aware it can be done with ng-include, but I'm not planning on including dozens of external dependencies with a couple of characters each just to make this work. There must be a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: I think I understand now.  I've updated my answer with a more generic templated approach.

Comment: Instead of replacing the element you avoid creating it in first place by passing down the tempting function - clever workaround!

Answer (score 1):

The compiled part of your template need to refer as child only instead on `child.html()`.
Change your code at 3 places from `$element.append(child.html());` to `$element.append(child);`

This will start printing the depth value you are looking for. Is there anything else you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your html might not be sanitized that's why it is not compiling try using ngSanatize ti might solve your problem **https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize** it will remove all the potentially dangerous tokens and will return you a proper html.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to the html(), don't use child.html().

Use the child itself.

Check the documentation here

- [element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)
- [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Check the snippet below. Added based on the sample snippet in your question

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.directive("test", function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      depth: "="
    },
    link: function linker($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var child = angular.element("<child depth='depth'/>");
      child = $compile(child)($scope);
      $element.append(child);
    }
  }
});
app.directive("child", function($compile) {
  function getTemplate(depth) {
      return depth % 2 == 0 ? "<even depth='depth-1'/>" : "<odd depth='depth-1'/>"
  }
  return {
    scope: {
      depth: "="
    },
    link: function linker($scope, $element) {
      if ($scope.depth == 0) {
        var child = angular.element("<span ng-bind='depth'/>");
        child = $compile(child)($scope);
        $element.append(child);
      } else {
        var child = angular.element(getTemplate($scope.depth));
        child = $compile(child)($scope);
        $element.append(child);
      }
    }
  }
})
app.directive("odd", function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      depth: "="
    },
    link: function linker($scope, $element) {
      var child = angular.element("<child depth='depth'/>");
      child = $compile(child)($scope);
      $element.append(child);
    }
  }
})
app.directive("even", function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      depth: "="
    },
    link: function linker($scope, $element) {
      var child = angular.element("<child depth='depth'/>");
      child = $compile(child)($scope);
      $element.append(child);
    }
  }
})
var controller = app.controller("controller", function($scope) {});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px !important;
  font-size: 30px;
}

test,
child,
even,
odd {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

test {
  background-color: aliceblue !important;
}

child {
  background-color: beige !important;
}

even {
  background-color: lightgreen !important;
}

odd {
  background-color: lightcoral !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <test depth="4"></test>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle is perfectly fine, the only problem is a small bit of logic.

When you compile the child directive you shouldn't append `child.html()` simply because that will append an HTML without bindings and watchers connected to them. Instead, you should append the whole child

https://jsfiddle.net/eg1e1aLz/2/

```
child = $compile(child)($scope);
$element.append(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm missing the context of what you're trying to accomplish, but I don't believe you need to use sub directives or anything like that. You can just use the test directive and continuously build out the children and then bind the scope to the last one:

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .directive("test", function ($compile) {
        return {
            scope: {
                depth: "="
            },
            link: function linker($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                var element = $element;
                for (var x = 0; x < $scope.depth; x++) {
                    var elementType = x % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
                    var subElement = angular.element(document.createElement(elementType));
                    element.append(subElement);
                    element = subElement;
                }
                var span = angular.element('<span ng-bind="depth" />');
                element.append(span);
                $compile(span)($scope);
            }
        }
    })
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ffyv0zmy/

I realise in your example you want the output to be "0" for the depth but you can hard code that as I'm not sure as to it's purpose.

Resulting HTML:

```
<test depth="4" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <even>
        <odd>
            <even>
                <odd>
                    <span ng-bind="depth" class="ng-binding ng-scope">4</span>
                </odd>
            </even>
        </odd>
    </even>
</test>
```

The nice thing about this is you don't have to attach scope to the even/odd elements unless you want too.

You can still wire up directives to each of the odd/even elements but then you'll have to $compile the $element instead to attach all the scopes.